# How can I pass an array to $stmt->execute()?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to rewrite some code to eliminate the `call_user_func_array` calls, and have the following code so far :

```
if($stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql)) {
    $bind_arguments = $this->params;

    // remove first element (eg. 'ssiss')
    $bind_arguments = array_shift($bind_arguments);

    // execute query passing values
    $res = $stmt->execute($bind_arguments);

}
```

Here is a `var_export` of `$this->params` :

```
array ( 0 => 's', 1 => 'admin', )
```

`$res` always evaluates to `null` when trying the above method.  According to [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#116281), it appears that everything is correct, except my array has integer keys, and there is an additional `,` after the last element.

What do I need to do to format this array (removing the first element), to pass to the `$stmt->execute` method as the variable containing the array elements (this is not a static array. elements in it are modified by other methods in the class to add or remove elements from it).

Comment: This is notoriously difficult in *mysqli* but trivial in PDO. Consider switching

Comment: mysqli::execute (oo interface) doesn't need an array inside http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Comment: FYI, the [comment you linked to](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#116281) is talking about PDO, not MySQLi

Comment: `$bind_arguments = array_shift($bind_arguments);` assigning shifted argument to `$bind_arguments`... You not passing array. You passing it's first element.

Comment: @Ghost - ya, i just noticed that. I liked the doc for PDO.   I guess there is no way to use mysqlnd and pass params in a dynamic manner.   I find prepared statements such a pita of repetition code.  Bind results, bind params,  it's horrible esp when dealing with tables that have lots of fields, or joins.  Has anyone ever successfully wrapped this to return results ?

Comment: @Num6 - also, that is incorrect.  See [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) . The return value of `array_shift( &arr )` is `&arr` minus the first element.  :)

Comment: @SamuelJackson _Returns the **shifted value**, or NULL if array is empty or is not an array._ http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to make things straight: **you cannot pass an array to mysqli_execute()** as this function accepts no parameters at all. What you really need is to pass an array to *mysqli_bind_param()*

However, the only way around call_user_func_array call is a *splat* operator available since PHP 5.6

```
function query($query, $params = NULL, $types = NULL)
{
    $statement = $this->mysqli->prepare($select);
    $types = $types ?: str_repeat('s', count($params));
    $statement->bind_param($types, ...$params);
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement;
}
```

Yet the preferred and bullet-proof solution would be apparently switching to PDO, which indeed has the capability of sending an array with parameters right into execute().

Comment: is `...` a term, or just signaling for 'other stuff' ?

Comment: @SamuelJackson its a [relatively] new operator in PHP, check http://php.net/manual/ru/migration56.new-features.php for "Argument unpacking"

Comment: Nice.  <3 for this feature.  Tried to google it before you replied and you would be amazed at the stuff that comes up searching for `"..." php operator`  :)

Comment: Marking this as correct as reading up on that operator (5.6) is pretty cool, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work for me.  Is there something aside from having php 5.6 i need to enable support for it ?  I don't get any error, but I tried both as `$bind_arguments = $this->params; $types = array_shift($bind_arguments); $stmt->bind_param( $types, ...$bind_arguments );` and `$stmt->bind_param( ...$this->params );`. Neither give an error but they produce the same result where I can't get any results from it after `$stmt->execute()` .

Comment: you cannot make two calls to bind_param. it should be only one. in your case you should get rid of array shift and make something like this `$stmt->bind_param(...$this->params)`.

Comment: But for my life I won't understand why all this hassle when there is PDO

Comment: First, the `and` meant an alternative way, not simultaneously. Meaning I tried 'method 1' AND 'method 2'  :)  .  Second, I am borking around with PDO at the same time, however this code should work -- in theory ?  (fyi  `$this->params` contains the field type string - eg :  'sisssiss' etc as the first value in the array  .. if you hadn't guessed that already)

Comment: what is the exact content of $this->params?

Comment: by the way, does it pass prepare?

Comment: Updated last comment  :)  was already clarifying that.  I presumed it was discernible from the first attempt removing the first element and passing it as `$types`.  I clarified anyway.

Comment: Consider everything I offer up to be contained within the `if($stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql)) {  .. stuff here ...  }` condition in my original question.

Comment: Programming is not a guesswork. what you *think* of a variable contents can be dramatically different from what is actually there. Either way, you have to enable error reporting and see what error you get. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/285587

Comment: Programming is not guess work, correct.  Interpreting code is also following logic flow and naming conventions to determine coding pattern and figure out what the code does.  For example, if I said `$x = 5;  $y = 20;  echo $y * $x;` it isn't hard to see what that does even without naming convention.  In my examples supplied in the comments here, `$types` (same var name you used) ` = array_shift($bind_params);` shows very clearly that the first value is at least assumed to contain the requisite composite string as required by -- looking at next lines .. `bind_param`.

Comment: Breaking it down even further, I could write entire books on every single line, but I truly do assume basic knowledge of the commands (which you have since you showed me the `...` operator), so I really don't understand where you would have problems understanding the snippet unless you assume that I have things other than expected data stored in those values. If that is the case, I could simply tell you - No.  I have the requisite values as `call_user_func_array` WORKS!!!   which it wouldn't work as expected if I had those values off. I would get a `bind_param` error message.

Comment: For the code snippet `$x = 5; $y = 20; echo $y * $x;` values for `$x` and `$y` are clearly seen. but for `$this->params` variable it is not. That's the difference.

Answer (score -2):

Array should be associative array and key name should be column name of table and data should be value of key. Like the following:

```
$arr = [ 'column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2' ];
```

than use `$res = $stmt->execute($arr);`

Comment: from what i saw in the docs, that is one way, but the other way is just the values alone

Comment: insert into table (column1,column2) values (?,?),(?,?) and pass the array in execute($arr) no need to use associative array.